# How to remove Non-English characters in Trino

Tags: regex, presto, trino

I am trying to remove non-english characters using Trino. As I am new to this, I am not sure what operator to use as ~ unusable . This is my current code:

```
Select
translationid,
medium
from translation
where medium ~ '[^A-Za-z_]'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
translationid,
medium
from translation
where not regexp_like(medium, '[^A-Za-z_]')
```